# How do I disconnect the power from a USB host port from the shell?

Tags: linux, usb, shell, power

How can I from the shell remove and apply USB power to one of the host USB ports in my machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that this cannot be done, which I kind of already suspected.

The advice found in some places about echoing `on` and `suspend` to `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb?/power/level` does not really remove power from the USB host port, it merely requests the device to go into suspend mode, and vice-versa.

I solved my problem by attaching a USB hub with an external power supply, and then cutting the USB 5V wire in the USB cable going from the host machine to the USB. Then I can turn power on an off from my device via an external power relay connected to the USB hub power supply.

Answer (score 1):

This was asked on Stackoverflow and really should have been migrated here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux

Comment: Funny thing is, that answers is not correct. Echoing suspend to that file will _request_ the device to power off (or suspend), but there will still be 5V on pin 1 in the USB cable, thus the device will still draw power from the USB port.